# How to predeliver WMA DRM licenses?

Tags: c++, drm, wma

I'm trying to install WMA DRM licenses files silently so that users would not have to play each song and acknowledge for each license.

I figured out that I need to do something like this :

```
HRESULT res = CoCreateInstance(__uuidof(RMGetLicense),NULL,CLSCTX_ALL,__uuidof(IRMGetLicense ),(void**) &pLicense );
res = pLicense->GetLicenseFromURL(NULL, bstrURL);
```

The bstrURL is expected to contain a keyID as a parameter, which allow to retrieve the file matching with the music file. I can't find how to get this keyID back from the WMA file.

I may get the problem wrongly though. Am I in the good way ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to pass header object as a first parameter. More information is in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb614588%28VS.85%29.aspx)